Old (pre 1980) story in which a man is given a beautiful "woman" in exchange for some service to a demon
What I recall is that the chief demon tells the man the despite the woman also actually being a fearsome demon, the man would never see this and she would be as affectionate as any woman.
The chief demon also says something like that despite his own appearance as a human, he is much more horrifying than the demon disguised as a woman -- the disguised demon, compared to the chief demon, would seem like a friendly puppy dog, but only in comparison.
I am trying to find out the name of the story. I believe the "puppy dog" line was in fact in the story.
